# How to extract the following 2-3 lines?

Tags: regex

Hi everyone i would like to extract the following `Text`. I have provided my **regular expression** below but its not going according to the output I want.

Output I want:

1. Extract Title
2. Extract 2nd line below title if there is, extract it. If not, move on.
3. Extract the Address (Only for address: regardless new line or not)

**Regular expression:**

```
/(.+?)\s*(\d+.*Singapore\s+\d{6}\b|\d+.*S\d{6})\b/g
```

Comment: Are you parsing the text multiple entries together as it is provided in your question or are you assuming only the first row is a title and the total length of text is 3 lines? If text can be over 3 lines what information guarantees 2nd line is additional information and not an address?

Comment: I believe there is no way to determine if 2nd line is additional info or an address. Is there another better way to do this?

Comment: It's hard to say with current info, but you could try something like `/(^.+\n)(^.+\n)?(^\d+.*\sSingapore,?\s\d{6})/gm` [demo](https://regexr.com/50hal)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Its a perfect solution! Exactly how like i wanted it to be.. But mind if i ask what is `/gm`?

Comment: `g` - global flag, meaning there can be multiple matches for same regex, without it you will only get the first result (if you parse each entry separate you don't need it). `m` - multiline flag, looks for matches in multiple lines of text, without it the match needs to be in a single line.

Comment: Great explanation. I got it now. Thank you so much for your time and effort to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(^.+\n)(^.+\n)?(^\d+.*\sSingapore,?\s\d{6})/gm
```

1. `(^.+\n)` - capture title

   - `()` - defines capture group
   - `^` - matches beginning of the line
   - `.+` - matches 1 or more character
   - `\n` - matches new line
2. `(^.+\n)?` - capture 2nd line

   - `?` - matches the group 0 or 1 times (since this line is optional)
3. `(^\d+.*\sSingapore,?\s\d{6})` - capture address

   - `\d+` - matches 1 or more digit
   - `.*` - matches any character 0 or more times (maybe you need to modify it to be required)
   - `\s` - matches a whitespace
   - `Singapore` - matches the word Singapore
   - `,?` - matches a comma 0 or 1 times (remove `?` if comma is required)
   - `\s` - matches a whitespace
   - `\d{6}` - matches 6 digits
4. `gm`

   - `g` - global flag, allows you to find multiple matches in the text. Only needed if your text contains more than one set of title/description/address.
   - `m` - multiline flag, looks for matches in the whole text, not in a single line.